# Application design in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm new to Spring MVC and trying out a simple project.It will contain a simple adding, viewing, updating and deleting user work flows. It will have login page and once authenticated the user will be taken to a welcome screen which will have links to add, view, update and delete users. Clicking on any of the links will take to individual pages where the user can do the specific tasks. What I'm doing here is, I'm using a MultiActionController to group together all requests related to User work flow. So the request from "Add User" link will handled by the addUser method in the UserController which will redirect the user to the "Add User" page, and the user can then fill in the details and save the new user. Now here is where I'm getting confused. Where should I put the save process of the new user, should I put that in new method inside UserController, or use the same "addUser" method. What is the best way to handle this kind of scenario.

I hope I was able to clear my question.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to check the Petclinic example which is in the Spring distribution? There you can find all the CRUD operation examples and much more...

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example I suggest that you implement a "goto action page" method and a "perform action" mthod in your UserController.  For the AddUser operation, the "goto action page" method might be `AddUserPage()` which performs any necessary initialization and setup required for the "add user" page then forwards the request to the "add user" web page and the "perform action" method might be `AddUser()` in which you implement the action of adding a user to your website.

For a "Delete User" action, you might have a "DeleteUserPage" and a "DeleteUser".  *etc.*

The idea here being that you need a method in the `MultiActonController` to send the user to the correct page and another method to implement the desired action.  The name of the methods is not important, but I suggest that you name them consistantly (for instance,  `xxxPage()` sends the user to the xxx activity page and `xxx()` implements the xxx activity).